# Best way to compare 2 XML documents in Java

Tags: java, xml, testing, parsing, comparison

I'm trying to write an automated test of an application that basically translates a custom message format into an XML message and sends it out the other end.  I've got a good set of input/output message pairs so all I need to do is send the input messages in and listen for the XML message to come out the other end.

When it comes time to compare the actual output to the expected output I'm running into some problems.  My first thought was just to do string comparisons on the expected and actual messages.  This doens't work very well because the example data we have isn't always formatted consistently and there are often times different aliases used for the XML namespace (and sometimes namespaces aren't used at all.)

I know I can parse both strings and then walk through each element and compare them myself and this wouldn't be too difficult to do, but I get the feeling there's a better way or a library I could leverage.

So, boiled down, the question is:

Given two Java Strings which both contain valid XML how would you go about determining if they are semantically equivalent?  Bonus points if you have a way to determine what the differences are.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Sounds like a job for XMLUnit

- http://www.xmlunit.org/
- https://github.com/xmlunit

Example:

```
public class SomeTest extends XMLTestCase {
  @Test
  public void test() {
    String xml1 = ...
    String xml2 = ...

    XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true); // ignore whitespace differences

    // can also compare xml Documents, InputSources, Readers, Diffs
    assertXMLEqual(xml1, xml2);  // assertXMLEquals comes from XMLTestCase
  }
}
```

Comment: I knew something like this had to be out there.  I can't believe Google didn't find it for me.  Thanks.

Comment: I'e had problems with XMLUNit in the past, it's been hyper-twitchy with XML API versions and hasn't proven reliable.  It's been a while since I ditched it for XOM, though, so maybe it's impoved since.

Comment: For beginners to XMLUnit, note that, by default, myDiff.similar() will return *false* if the control and test documents differ in indentation/newlines.  I expected this behavior from myDiff.identical(), and not from myDiff.similar(). Include XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true); in your setUp method to change the behavior for all tests in your test class, or use it in an individual test method to change the behavior for only that test.

Comment: @Stew thanks for your comment, just starting with XMLUnit and am sure would have faced this issue. +1

Comment: In case you are trying this with XMLUnit 2 on github, the 2 version it's a complete rewrite, so this example is for XMLUnit 1 on SourceForge. Also, the sourceforge page states "XMLUnit for Java 1.x will still be maintained".

Comment: This example Junit 3, which uses extends TestCase, which is really old school. A Junit 4 example would be much appreciated.

Comment: method is assertXMLEqual as from [XMLAssert.java](https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit/blob/master/xmlunit-legacy/src/main/java/org/custommonkey/xmlunit/XMLAssert.java).

Comment: @skaffman admittedly 10 years later.... but xmlunit works very well for me in JUnit 4 tests.

Comment: Notice that in the latest version of xmlunit, XMLUnit class is gone. Use CompareMatcher instead. [Docs](https://github.com/xmlunit/user-guide/wiki/CompareMatcher)

Answer (score 42):

The following will check if the documents are equal using standard JDK libraries.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
dbf.setCoalescing(true);
dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
dbf.setIgnoringComments(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc1 = db.parse(new File("file1.xml"));
doc1.normalizeDocument();

Document doc2 = db.parse(new File("file2.xml"));
doc2.normalizeDocument();

Assert.assertTrue(doc1.isEqualNode(doc2));
```

normalize() is there to make sure there are no cycles (there technically wouldn't be any)

The above code will require the white spaces to be the same within the elements though, because it preserves and evaluates it.  The standard XML parser that comes with Java does not allow you to set a feature to provide a canonical version or understand `xml:space` if that is going to be a problem then you may need a replacement XML parser such as xerces or use JDOM.

Comment: This perfectly works for XMLs without namespaces or with "normalized" namespace prefixes. I doubt that it works if one XML is <ns1:a xmlns:ns1="ns" /> and the other is <ns2:a xmlns:ns2="ns" />

Comment: dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true) does not have the result I would expect the <root>name</root> is not equal with <root> name </name> with this solution (padded with two space) but XMLUnit gives the equal result in this case (JDK8)

Comment: For me it doesn't ignore line breaks, which is a problem.

Comment: `setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(false)`

Answer (score 28):

[Xom](http://xom.nu) has a Canonicalizer utility which turns your DOMs into a regular form, which you can then stringify and compare.  So regardless of whitespace irregularities or attribute ordering, you can get regular, predictable comparisons of your documents.

This works especially well in IDEs that have dedicated visual String comparators, like Eclipse. You get a visual representation of the semantic differences between the documents.

Answer (score 28):

The latest version of [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/) can help the job of asserting two XML are equal. Also `XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace()` and `XMLUnit.setIgnoreAttributeOrder()` may be necessary to the case in question.

See working code of a simple example of XML Unit use below.

```
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.DetailedDiff;
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLUnit;
import org.junit.Assert;

public class TestXml {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String result = "<abc             attr=\"value1\"                title=\"something\">            </abc>";
        // will be ok
        assertXMLEquals("<abc attr=\"value1\" title=\"something\"></abc>", result);
    }

    public static void assertXMLEquals(String expectedXML, String actualXML) throws Exception {
        XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);
        XMLUnit.setIgnoreAttributeOrder(true);

        DetailedDiff diff = new DetailedDiff(XMLUnit.compareXML(expectedXML, actualXML));

        List<?> allDifferences = diff.getAllDifferences();
        Assert.assertEquals("Differences found: "+ diff.toString(), 0, allDifferences.size());
    }

}
```

If using Maven, add this to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is perfect for folks who need to compare from a static method.

Comment: This is perfect answer. Thank you.. However I need to ignore the nodes which are not existent. Since I do not want to see in the result output such a output:  Expected presence of child node "null" but was ......How can I do that? Regards. @acdcjunior

Comment: XMLUnit.setIgnoreAttributeOrder(true); does not work. If some nodes have a different order, the comparison will fail.

Comment: [UPDATE] this solution works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33695041/compare-xml-ignoring-element-order

Comment: You do realize "IgnoreAttributeOrder" means ignore attribute order and not ignore nodes order, right?

Comment: @acdcjunior If the nodes are at different places... will this work?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti Apparently only when you also add `.withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.byName))`.

Comment: DiffBuilder.compare(bufferedReaderExistingFile)
              .withTest(bufferedReaderNewFile)
              .ignoreComments()
              .ignoreWhitespace()
              .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.byName))
              .checkForSimilar()
              .build();

Comment: @acdcjunior: I have the above code still it says files are diffrent

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti hm... that's bad... I'm sorry, I got nothing else 

Answer (score 10):

Building on [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22850/tom)'s answer, here's an example using XMLUnit v2.

It uses these maven dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlunit-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlunit-matchers</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

..and here's the test code

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.xmlunit.matchers.CompareMatcher.isIdenticalTo;
import org.xmlunit.builder.Input;
import org.xmlunit.input.WhitespaceStrippedSource;

public class SomeTest extends XMLTestCase {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        String result = "<root></root>";
        String expected = "<root>  </root>";

        // ignore whitespace differences
        // https://github.com/xmlunit/user-guide/wiki/Providing-Input-to-XMLUnit#whitespacestrippedsource
        assertThat(result, isIdenticalTo(new WhitespaceStrippedSource(Input.from(expected).build())));

        assertThat(result, isIdenticalTo(Input.from(expected).build())); // will fail due to whitespace differences
    }
}
```

The documentation that outlines this is https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit#comparing-two-documents

Answer (score 8):

Thanks, I extended this, try this ...

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class XmlDiff 
{
    private boolean nodeTypeDiff = true;
    private boolean nodeValueDiff = true;

    public boolean diff( String xml1, String xml2, List<String> diffs ) throws Exception
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        dbf.setCoalescing(true);
        dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
        dbf.setIgnoringComments(true);
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();


        Document doc1 = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml1.getBytes()));
        Document doc2 = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml2.getBytes()));

        doc1.normalizeDocument();
        doc2.normalizeDocument();

        return diff( doc1, doc2, diffs );

    }

    /**
     * Diff 2 nodes and put the diffs in the list 
     */
    public boolean diff( Node node1, Node node2, List<String> diffs ) throws Exception
    {
        if( diffNodeExists( node1, node2, diffs ) )
        {
            return true;
        }

        if( nodeTypeDiff )
        {
            diffNodeType(node1, node2, diffs );
        }

        if( nodeValueDiff )
        {
            diffNodeValue(node1, node2, diffs );
        }


        System.out.println(node1.getNodeName() + "/" + node2.getNodeName());

        diffAttributes( node1, node2, diffs );
        diffNodes( node1, node2, diffs );

        return diffs.size() > 0;
    }

    /**
     * Diff the nodes
     */
    public boolean diffNodes( Node node1, Node node2, List<String> diffs ) throws Exception
    {
        //Sort by Name
        Map<String,Node> children1 = new LinkedHashMap<String,Node>();      
        for( Node child1 = node1.getFirstChild(); child1 != null; child1 = child1.getNextSibling() )
        {
            children1.put( child1.getNodeName(), child1 );
        }

        //Sort by Name
        Map<String,Node> children2 = new LinkedHashMap<String,Node>();      
        for( Node child2 = node2.getFirstChild(); child2!= null; child2 = child2.getNextSibling() )
        {
            children2.put( child2.getNodeName(), child2 );
        }

        //Diff all the children1
        for( Node child1 : children1.values() )
        {
            Node child2 = children2.remove( child1.getNodeName() );
            diff( child1, child2, diffs );
        }

        //Diff all the children2 left over
        for( Node child2 : children2.values() )
        {
            Node child1 = children1.get( child2.getNodeName() );
            diff( child1, child2, diffs );
        }

        return diffs.size() > 0;
    }


    /**
     * Diff the nodes
     */
    public boolean diffAttributes( Node node1, Node node2, List<String> diffs ) throws Exception
    {        
        //Sort by Name
        NamedNodeMap nodeMap1 = node1.getAttributes();
        Map<String,Node> attributes1 = new LinkedHashMap<String,Node>();        
        for( int index = 0; nodeMap1 != null && index < nodeMap1.getLength(); index++ )
        {
            attributes1.put( nodeMap1.item(index).getNodeName(), nodeMap1.item(index) );
        }

        //Sort by Name
        NamedNodeMap nodeMap2 = node2.getAttributes();
        Map<String,Node> attributes2 = new LinkedHashMap<String,Node>();        
        for( int index = 0; nodeMap2 != null && index < nodeMap2.getLength(); index++ )
        {
            attributes2.put( nodeMap2.item(index).getNodeName(), nodeMap2.item(index) );

        }

        //Diff all the attributes1
        for( Node attribute1 : attributes1.values() )
        {
            Node attribute2 = attributes2.remove( attribute1.getNodeName() );
            diff( attribute1, attribute2, diffs );
        }

        //Diff all the attributes2 left over
        for( Node attribute2 : attributes2.values() )
        {
            Node attribute1 = attributes1.get( attribute2.getNodeName() );
            diff( attribute1, attribute2, diffs );
        }

        return diffs.size() > 0;
    }
    /**
     * Check that the nodes exist
     */
    public boolean diffNodeExists( Node node1, Node node2, List<String> diffs ) throws Exception
    {
        if( node1 == null && node2 == null )
        {
            diffs.add( getPath(node2) + ":node " + node1 + "!=" + node2 + "\n" );
            return true;
        }

        if( node1 == null && node2 != null )
        {
            diffs.add( getPath(node2) + ":node " + node1 + "!=" + node2.getNodeName() );
            return true;
        }

        if( node1 != null && node2 == null )
        {
            diffs.add( getPath(node1) + ":node " + node1.getNodeName() + "!=" + node2 );
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Diff the Node Type
     */
    public boolean diffNodeType( Node node1, Node node2, List<String> diffs ) throws Exception
    {       
        if( node1.getNodeType() != node2.getNodeType() ) 
        {
            diffs.add( getPath(node1) + ":type " + node1.getNodeType() + "!=" + node2.getNodeType() );
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Diff the Node Value
     */
    public boolean diffNodeValue( Node node1, Node node2, List<String> diffs ) throws Exception
    {       
        if( node1.getNodeValue() == null && node2.getNodeValue() == null )
        {
            return false;
        }

        if( node1.getNodeValue() == null && node2.getNodeValue() != null )
        {
            diffs.add( getPath(node1) + ":type " + node1 + "!=" + node2.getNodeValue() );
            return true;
        }

        if( node1.getNodeValue() != null && node2.getNodeValue() == null )
        {
            diffs.add( getPath(node1) + ":type " + node1.getNodeValue() + "!=" + node2 );
            return true;
        }

        if( !node1.getNodeValue().equals( node2.getNodeValue() ) )
        {
            diffs.add( getPath(node1) + ":type " + node1.getNodeValue() + "!=" + node2.getNodeValue() );
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


    /**
     * Get the node path
     */
    public String getPath( Node node )
    {
        StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder();

        do
        {           
            path.insert(0, node.getNodeName() );
            path.insert( 0, "/" );
        }
        while( ( node = node.getParentNode() ) != null );

        return path.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Quite late, but just wanted to note that this piece of code has a bug: In diffNodes(), node2 is not referenced - the second loop reuses node1 incorrectly (I edited the code to fix this). Also, it has 1 limitation: Due to the way to child maps are keyed, this diff does not support the case where element names are not unique, i.e. elements containing repeatable child elements.

Answer (score 7):

[AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) 1.4+ has specific assertions to compare XML content:

```
String expectedXml = "<foo />";
String actualXml = "<bar />";
assertThat(actualXml).isXmlEqualTo(expectedXml);
```

Here is the [Documentation](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/wiki/New-and-noteworthy#xml-assertions)

Comment: Yet trivial namespace prefix difference between two documents makes AssertJ fail. AssertJ is a great tool, but the job is really for XMLUnit.

Answer (score 4):

Below code works for me

```
String xml1 = ...
String xml2 = ...
XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);
XMLUnit.setIgnoreAttributeOrder(true);
XMLAssert.assertXMLEqual(actualxml, xmlInDb);
```

Comment: Any context? Library reference?

Answer (score 4):

### Using XMLUnit 2.x

In the `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlunit-assertj3</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Test implementation (using junit 5) :

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.xmlunit.assertj3.XmlAssert;

public class FooTest {

    @Test
    public void compareXml() {
        //
        String xmlContentA = "<foo></foo>";
        String xmlContentB = "<foo></foo>";
        //
        XmlAssert.assertThat(xmlContentA).and(xmlContentB).areSimilar();
    }
}
```

Other methods : `areIdentical()`, `areNotIdentical()`, `areNotSimilar()`

More details (configuration of `assertThat(~).and(~)` and examples) in this [documentation page](https://github.com/xmlunit/user-guide/wiki/CompareAssert).

XMLUnit also has (among other features) a [`DifferenceEvaluator`](https://github.com/xmlunit/user-guide/wiki/DifferenceEvaluator) to do more precise comparisons.

[XMLUnit website](https://www.xmlunit.org/)

Answer (score 3):

skaffman seems to be giving a good answer.

another way is probably to format the XML using a commmand line utility like xmlstarlet(http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) and then format both the strings and then use any diff utility(library) to diff the resulting output files. I don't know if this is a good solution when issues are with namespaces.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [Altova DiffDog](http://www.altova.com/diffdog/diff-merge-tool.html) which has options to compare XML files structurally (ignoring string data).

This means that (if checking the 'ignore text' option):

```
<foo a="xxx" b="xxx">xxx</foo>
```

and

```
<foo b="yyy" a="yyy">yyy</foo>
```

are equal in the sense that they have structural equality. This is handy if you have example files that differ in data, but not structure!

Comment: Only minus is that it is not free (99€ for a pro license), with 30 day trial.

Comment: I have found only the utility (http://www.altova.com/diffdog/diff-merge-tool.html); nice to have a library.

Answer (score 2):

I required the same functionality as requested in the main question. As I was not allowed to use any 3rd party libraries, I have created my own solution basing on @Archimedes Trajano solution.

Following is my solution.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

/**
 * Asserts for asserting XML strings.
 */
public final class AssertXml {

    private AssertXml() {
    }

    private static Pattern NAMESPACE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("xmlns:(ns\\d+)=\"(.*?)\"");

    /**
     * Asserts that two XML are of identical content (namespace aliases are ignored).
     * 
     * @param expectedXml expected XML
     * @param actualXml actual XML
     * @throws Exception thrown if XML parsing fails
     */
    public static void assertEqualXmls(String expectedXml, String actualXml) throws Exception {
        // Find all namespace mappings
        Map<String, String> fullnamespace2newAlias = new HashMap<String, String>();
        generateNewAliasesForNamespacesFromXml(expectedXml, fullnamespace2newAlias);
        generateNewAliasesForNamespacesFromXml(actualXml, fullnamespace2newAlias);

        for (Entry<String, String> entry : fullnamespace2newAlias.entrySet()) {
            String newAlias = entry.getValue();
            String namespace = entry.getKey();
            Pattern nsReplacePattern = Pattern.compile("xmlns:(ns\\d+)=\"" + namespace + "\"");
            expectedXml = transletaNamespaceAliasesToNewAlias(expectedXml, newAlias, nsReplacePattern);
            actualXml = transletaNamespaceAliasesToNewAlias(actualXml, newAlias, nsReplacePattern);
        }

        // nomralize namespaces accoring to given mapping

        DocumentBuilder db = initDocumentParserFactory();

        Document expectedDocuemnt = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(expectedXml.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
        expectedDocuemnt.normalizeDocument();

        Document actualDocument = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(actualXml.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
        actualDocument.normalizeDocument();

        if (!expectedDocuemnt.isEqualNode(actualDocument)) {
            Assert.assertEquals(expectedXml, actualXml); //just to better visualize the diffeences i.e. in eclipse
        }
    }


    private static DocumentBuilder initDocumentParserFactory() throws ParserConfigurationException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(false);
        dbf.setCoalescing(true);
        dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
        dbf.setIgnoringComments(true);
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        return db;
    }

    private static String transletaNamespaceAliasesToNewAlias(String xml, String newAlias, Pattern namespacePattern) {
        Matcher nsMatcherExp = namespacePattern.matcher(xml);
        if (nsMatcherExp.find()) {
            xml = xml.replaceAll(nsMatcherExp.group(1) + "[:]", newAlias + ":");
            xml = xml.replaceAll(nsMatcherExp.group(1) + "=", newAlias + "=");
        }
        return xml;
    }

    private static void generateNewAliasesForNamespacesFromXml(String xml, Map<String, String> fullnamespace2newAlias) {
        Matcher nsMatcher = NAMESPACE_PATTERN.matcher(xml);
        while (nsMatcher.find()) {
            if (!fullnamespace2newAlias.containsKey(nsMatcher.group(2))) {
                fullnamespace2newAlias.put(nsMatcher.group(2), "nsTr" + (fullnamespace2newAlias.size() + 1));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It compares two XML strings and takes care of any mismatching namespace mappings by translating them to unique values in both input strings.

Can be fine tuned i.e. in case of translation of namespaces. But for my requirements just does the job.

Answer (score 1):

This will compare full string XMLs (reformatting them on the way). It makes it easy to work with your IDE (IntelliJ, Eclipse), cos you just click and visually see the difference in the XML files.

```
import org.apache.xml.security.c14n.CanonicalizationException;
import org.apache.xml.security.c14n.Canonicalizer;
import org.apache.xml.security.c14n.InvalidCanonicalizerException;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.DOMImplementationLS;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSSerializer;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

import static org.apache.xml.security.Init.init;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class XmlUtils {
    static {
        init();
    }

    public static String toCanonicalXml(String xml) throws InvalidCanonicalizerException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, CanonicalizationException, IOException {
        Canonicalizer canon = Canonicalizer.getInstance(Canonicalizer.ALGO_ID_C14N_OMIT_COMMENTS);
        byte canonXmlBytes[] = canon.canonicalize(xml.getBytes());
        return new String(canonXmlBytes);
    }

    public static String prettyFormat(String input) throws TransformerException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        InputSource src = new InputSource(new StringReader(input));
        Element document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(src).getDocumentElement();
        Boolean keepDeclaration = input.startsWith("<?xml");
        DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();
        DOMImplementationLS impl = (DOMImplementationLS) registry.getDOMImplementation("LS");
        LSSerializer writer = impl.createLSSerializer();
        writer.getDomConfig().setParameter("format-pretty-print", Boolean.TRUE);
        writer.getDomConfig().setParameter("xml-declaration", keepDeclaration);
        return writer.writeToString(document);
    }

    public static void assertXMLEqual(String expected, String actual) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException, CanonicalizationException, InvalidCanonicalizerException, TransformerException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException {
        String canonicalExpected = prettyFormat(toCanonicalXml(expected));
        String canonicalActual = prettyFormat(toCanonicalXml(actual));
        assertEquals(canonicalExpected, canonicalActual);
    }
}
```

I prefer this to XmlUnit because the client code (test code) is cleaner.

Comment: This works fine in two tests I did now, with same XML and with different XML. With IntelliJ diff it the differences in the compareds XML are easy to spot.

Comment: By the way, you'll need this dependency if you use Maven: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Using JExamXML with java application

```
    import com.a7soft.examxml.ExamXML;
    import com.a7soft.examxml.Options;

       .................

       // Reads two XML files into two strings
       String s1 = readFile("orders1.xml");
       String s2 = readFile("orders.xml");

       // Loads options saved in a property file
       Options.loadOptions("options");

       // Compares two Strings representing XML entities
       System.out.println( ExamXML.compareXMLString( s1, s2 ) );
```

Answer (score -2):

Since you say "semantically equivalent" I assume you mean that you want to do more than just literally verify that the xml outputs are (string) equals, and that you'd want something like

<foo>   some stuff here</foo></code>

and

<foo>some stuff here</foo></code>

do read as equivalent. Ultimately it's going to matter how you're defining "semantically equivalent" on whatever object you're reconstituting the message from. Simply build that object from the messages and use a custom equals() to define what you're looking for.

Comment: Not an answer but a question.