# how to compare part of xml to a part of another xml?

Tags: java, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to compare 2 XML documents in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141993/best-way-to-compare-2-xml-documents-in-java)

in java, I have 2 xml files, with different root elements.
I know that a part of the first onbe equals to a part of the second one.
what is the best way to compare?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try with XMLUnit - http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/