# How to compare document objects in java with XERCES?

Tags: java, xml, xerces, jdom

I am trying to compare two Document objects and try to make operation according to result.
For example I will have a Document object like,

```
<head>
<value> </value>
</head>
```

and I will compare with another document object like,

```
<head>
</head>
```

If the two Document objects will not be in the same format, I want to do some operation.
Can you please help me about this situation ?

Thank you all

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141993/best-way-to-compare-2-xml-documents-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/) is designed to do this kind of comparison, specifically for unit testing. But it can surely be used for other uses as well.