# Compare 2 xml payloads using Java

Tags: java, xml

Iam automating rest services and in this automation i want to submit a xml payload and in the given response i will get the same payload.My question is to verify the out put and input pay loads are same(commented attributes and every thing should be compared)

**Input**

```
   <abc xsi:schemaLocation="https://abc.abc.com xyz.xsd" schemaVersion="1.0" xmlns="https://abc.abc.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> <details>    <name>pawan</name>    <School>patrick</School>
         </details>
```

**Output**

```
   <abc xsi:schemaLocation="https://abc.abc.com xyz.xsd" schemaVersion="1.0" xmlns="https://abc.abc.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<details>
   <name>pawan</name>
   <School>patrick</School>
         </details>
```

Can any one help me with sample code of java to compare weather the input and output pay loads are equal or not.

Comment: Are you expecting your sample "Input" and "Output" to be considered equal, as they only differ in whitespace?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to compare 2 XML documents in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141993/best-way-to-compare-2-xml-documents-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Try FileUtils.contentEquals(). It's part of the org.apache.commons.io package. You'll need to have the jar in build path before using this method.