# How compare Two XML Node Structures Delphi

Tags: xml, delphi, txmldocument, ixmldomdocument, ixmldomnode

Is there a way to compare two xml nodes in Delphi?

I am using the MSXML parser and loading the xml into an IXmlDOMDocument2.  The nodes are stored in an IXmlDOMNode.

I would be ok using Delphi's TXMLDocument if it helps.  I do not want to download any third party components.

I just want to compare the structures of the nodes, not the values.

I saw a similar post/utility for [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141993/best-way-to-compare-2-xml-documents-in-java), but nothing for Delphi.

Thank you!

Comment: Updated the question, no longer concerned about attributes or values.  Just interested in an easy way to compare the two structures.

Comment: How do you want the differences to be presented/described?

Comment: I am pretty flexible on this point.  Perhaps three stringlists passed by reference.  The first two would identify nodes that exist in one but not the other.  The third contains the differences.  I know that the nodes drill down, so the strings in the list would contain the node path.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to compare only the structure, you could convert your nodes into 'full paths' and compare them as strings.

E.g. Let's assume the trees:

### Tree A

```
Root -> Node1 -> Child1
              -> Child2
     -> Node2
```

### Tree B

```
Root -> Node1 -> Child1
     -> Node2
```

From the conversion to 'full paths' you'd get:

### Tree A

```
Root
Root\Node1
Root\Node1\Child1
Root\Node1\Child2
Root\Node2
```

### Tree B

```
Root
Root\Node1
Root\Node1\Child1
Root\Node2
```

By iterating on the lists of full paths you can quickly check and compare if they exist in the other tree. You can also easily find the nodes on the tree.