# XML Comparison using XMLUnit

Tags: java, xml, junit, xmlunit

I want to compare two XML files using XMLUnit (I don't want to reinvent something which is already present).

XML 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Product>
    <Property>
        <Container value="1">Test 01</Container>
        <Container value="3">Test 02</Container>
        <Container value="5">Test 03</Container>
    </Property>
</Product>
```

XML2:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Product>
    <Property>
        <Container value="3">Test 01</Container>
        <Container value="7">Test 02</Container>
        <Container value="1">Test 03</Container>
        <Container value="5">Test 04</Container>
    </Property>
</Product>
```

I want to compare the elements only if the node along with the attribute matches. Also if the position is different then it should be similar.

I have tried with DetailedDiff but it is showing a lot of results but I only want to extract  specific changes. Please give your seggestions.

Comment: This may help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141993/best-way-to-compare-2-xml-documents-in-java

Answer (score 1):

If you're after an order-independent comparison then `ElementQualifier` would help:

http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/userguide/html/ar01s03.html

> In some cases the order of elements in two pieces of XML may not be significant. If this is true, the DifferenceEngine needs help to determine which Elements to compare. This is the job of an ElementQualifier (see Section 3.4, “ElementQualifier”).

Specifically, [`ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier`](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/userguide/html/ar01s03.html#ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier) seems to match your requirements:

> Only Elements with the same name - and Namespace URI if present - as well as the same values for all attributes given in ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier's constructor qualify.