# Remove whitespaces in end tags jdom

Tags: java, xml, jdom, jdom-2

I am using JDom 2.0.5 to modify an xml. Also I have a Junit test case which check if it was correctly modified. It has an input xml, a method for testing (transformation xml) and a new xml (result). Later it compares output with a file which should be the final result.

```
FileUtils.contentEquals(newXml, modelXml);
```

But this is always false because every ending tag is modified by JDom automatically. I can't change the model because is a requirement that doesn't be modified.

```
Input: <properties/>
Output: <properties />    --> should be as input:: <properties/>
```

How can avoid that JDom changes this tags?

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
Document doc = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);

// Add, remove some elements ...

XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter(newXml, false));
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The "change" here is actually totally valid.  The extra space makes no difference to the meaning of the XML.

(Or to put it another way, the JDom data structure does not encode the presence or otherwise of non-significant whitespace in the source tags.  Therefore, JDom cannot reproduce the input XML's white-space when it formats the output XML.)

---

The real problem is that your *expectation* is incorrect.  You simply can't reliably compare XML documents as if they were character sequences.

Read this Q&A for various *correct* ways to compare XML in Java:

- [Best way to compare 2 XML documents in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141993/best-way-to-compare-2-xml-documents-in-java)

Comment: Both of them are valid and 'equal' xml  but you can see extra difference in git commit for example, or it can force to start some script as files are different

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone will need it.
To get rid of the extra space before the closing "/>" tags, it is enough to override the `printElement()` method in its inherited `AbstractXMLOutputProcessor` class.
For example:

```
public class MyXMLProcessor extends AbstractXMLOutputProcessor {
    protected void printElement(...) {
        ...
        // replace in two places:
        write(out, "/>");
        ...
    }
}
```

And then:

```
XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter(new MyXMLProcessor());
```