# how to compare two xml files depending on a specific attribute value?

Tags: java, xml, compare, xmlunit

i want to know if it is possible to make xmlunit compare only nodes that have the same value of a specific attribute.. for example in make case i want xmlunit to compare nodes which have the same value of MOID ( attribute )
here is two xml files :

controle.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
  <HWData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Header xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0"/>
    <NE MOID="WBTS-4073" NEType="WBTS">
     <EQHO MOID="EQHO-1-0" serialNumber="V7124400225">
       <UNIT MOID="UNIT-FAN-1" State="enabled" serialNumber="V735"></UNIT>
       <UNIT MOID="UNIT-FAN-3" State="enabled" serialNumber="V745"></UNIT>
       <UNIT MOID="UNIT-FAN-2" State="enabled" serialNumber="V734"></UNIT>
     </EQHO>
    </NE>
  </HWData>
```

test.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
  <HWData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Header xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0"/>
    <NE MOID="WBTS-4073" NEType="WBTS">
     <EQHO MOID="EQHO-1-0" serialNumber="V7124400225">
       <UNIT MOID="UNIT-FAN-2" State="enabled" serialNumber="V734"></UNIT>
       <UNIT MOID="UNIT-FAN-1" State="disabled" serialNumber="V735"></UNIT>
       <UNIT MOID="UNIT-FAN-3" State="enabled" serialNumber="V745"></UNIT>
     </EQHO>
    </NE>
  </HWData>
```

Is there a way to achieve that with xmlunit !!
any other suggestions are welcomed..
thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141993/best-way-to-compare-2-xml-documents-in-java