# XMLUnit outside unit test

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit

I was wondering if I could use `XMLUnit` outside unit test, in my application ( to compare XML ).

It seems intended for unit testing, so i feel like it should not be a good practice, but latest version of `XMLUnit 2.0.0-alpha-3` seems to do exactly stuff i want to do.

So, should I do it ?

Comment: You should. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141993/best-way-to-compare-2-xml-documents-in-java

Comment: Being useful outside of unit tests is a design goal of XMLUnit 2.x.