# How to compare two xmls by skipping few nodes?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xmlunit

I have two xmls in string format. Need to compare both of them by skipping few nodes. In the result only difference of node and corresponding values are required.

Suppose I have the following two xmls :

**Message -1**

```xml
<block4>
   <tag>
        <name>35B</name>
        <value>/GB/B0W1VM9</value>
   </tag>
</block4>
```

**Message - 2**

```xml
<block4>
   <tag>
        <name>35B</name>
        <value>/US/999999999
    NOT AVAILABLE AT PRESENT</value>
    </tag>
</block4>
```

I am using XMLUnit but I want to find the difference from few blocks and want to skip few nodes having specific values. like in `<tag>` value being : :PREV should be skipped.

**Note :** In the end want to print the result in excel.

Used the following code but not useful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16471601/3493471

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XMLUnit 2.x you can use a `NodeFilter` and suppress the nodes you want to skip. Something like

```
DiffBuilder b = DiffBuilder.compare(some-input)
    .withTest(some-test)
    .withNodeFilter(n -> !":PREV".equals(n.getTextContent()))
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can still use XMLUnit for that job, but you can't use the default settings. Instead, you may want to implement a custom `DifferenceEvaluator` that ignores certain attributes or nodes.

See [XMLUnit DifferenceEvaluator](https://github.com/xmlunit/user-guide/wiki/DifferenceEvaluator) for details and examples.