# How to compare two XML files with java?

Tags: java, xml

I need to compare two files with same tags, but they have some different values and I need to print three lists:

```
Set<Costo> list1 = read.getCostos("path1");
        Set<Costo> list2 = read.getCostos("path2");

        Set<Costo> list3 = ListaCostoUtil.listaConjunta(list1, list2);
        Set<Costo> plus = ListaCostoUtil.listaComplementoMenos(list3, list2);
        Set<Costo> minus = ListaCostoUtil.listaComplementoMas(list3, list2);
```

where `list1` is my first XML file and `list2` is the other, I need to print a `list3` where is a complete list of all the elements from `list1` and `list2`.

With list plus I just need to compare my `list3` with `list2` and throw all the elements that are not on `list2` with a "+" and it's the same with minus but just adding a "-", how could I start doing it? thanks

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141993/best-way-to-compare-2-xml-documents-in-java?

Comment: Do you  have an `equals` method in `Costo` class? Please post the `Costo` class