# What's the best way to validate an XML file against local XML file?

Tags: java, xml, unit-testing, automation

I'm developing some test framework. I suppose to validate the extremely complex XML responses with local data.

I thought to have local data in the CSV format and achieved some validation but I found the limitation of this frameworks that I can't validate complex data e.g.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <!DOCTYPE ResourceObject PUBLIC "abc_corp.dtd" "abc_corp.dtd">
 <ResourceObject displayName="abcd" identity="pqr" objectType="account" uuid="123456">
   <Attributes>
     <Map>
       <entry key="memberOf"/>
       <entry key="objectClass">
         <value>
           <List>
             <String>top</String>
             <String>person</String>
             <String>organizationalPerson</String>
             <String>user</String>
           </List>
         </value>
       </entry>
       <entry key="objectSid" value="S-1-5"/>
       <entry key="objectType" value="user"/>
          <value>
           <List>
             <Permission rights="allow:elasticmapreduce:Describe*" target="*"/>
             <Permission rights="allow:elasticmapreduce:List*" target="*"/>
             <Permission rights="allow:elasticmapreduce:ViewEventsFromAllClustersInConsole" target="*"/>
             <Permission rights="allow:s3:GetObject" target="*"/>
             <Permission rights="allow:s3:ListAllMyBuckets" target="*"/>
             <Permission rights="allow:s3:ListBucket" target="*"/>
             <Permission rights="allow:sdb:Select" target="*"/>
             <Permission rights="allow:cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics" target="*"/>
           </List>
         </value>
       </entry>
     </Map>
   </Attributes>
 </ResourceObject>
```

Out of above `XML` object below `entry` is something hard to represent in the `CSV` format

```
       <entry key="objectType" value="user"/>
          <value>
           <List>
             <Permission rights="allow:elasticmapreduce:Describe*" target="*"/>
             <Permission rights="allow:elasticmapreduce:List*" target="*"/>
             <Permission rights="allow:elasticmapreduce:ViewEventsFromAllClustersInConsole" target="*"/>
             <Permission rights="allow:s3:GetObject" target="*"/>
             <Permission rights="allow:s3:ListAllMyBuckets" target="*"/>
             <Permission rights="allow:s3:ListBucket" target="*"/>
             <Permission rights="allow:sdb:Select" target="*"/>
             <Permission rights="allow:cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics" target="*"/>
           </List>
         </value>
       </entry>
```

Or XML data which hold `list of maps` etc.

Is there any framework, library available which could validate such a complex XML data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these for reference..

1. https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/04/how-to-compare-two-xml-files-in-java.htm
2. [Best way to compare 2 XML documents in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141993/best-way-to-compare-2-xml-documents-in-java)

```
    //creating Diff instance to compare two XML files 
    Diff xmlDiff = new Diff(source, target); 

    //for getting detailed differences between two xml files 
    DetailedDiff detailXmlDiff = new DetailedDiff(xmlDiff);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @reeta-wani, seems interesting 